# Next.js API routes default response on error or no HTTP method match

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I'm working on [API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) in Next.js with every path is structured like this:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { query } = req;

  try {
    switch (req.method) {
      case "GET":
        // Do some GET stuff
        res.status(200).send(result);
        break;

      case "POST":
        // Do some POST stuff
        res.status(200).send(result);
        break;

      default:
        // No Matched Method
        res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Unprocessable Entity
    res.status(422).send(e);
  }
};
```

As you can see the `default` case and `catch` part will be duplicated all over the files. So, I wanted to know:

- Does Next.js has a built-in supports default response when there's no matched method or there's an error in processing the request?
- (If there's no built-in support) How can it be done?

---

Here's my idea of a solution if there's no built-in support:

- Use a middleware
- Create a function to wrap the API call before `export default`. I've tried to implement this but stuck at accessing `req` and `res` objects as in the code block below.

```js
const wrapAPICall = async (
  fn: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => void
) => {
  try {
    await fn(req, res); // Can't access req, res here
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(422).send(e); // Also can't access req, res here
  } finally {
    if (!res.headersSent) res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  }
};

const apiCall = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  // Does some API stuff
};

export default wrapAPICall(apiCall);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your wrapper solution is sound. To make it work you just need to return a function from the wrapper.

```js
const wrapAPICall = (
    fn: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => void
) => {
    return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        try {
            await fn(req, res);
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(422).send(e);
        } finally {
            if (!res.headersSent) res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `return`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I have found another solution rather than writing a custom wrapper is to use [`next-connect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect) which is a routing middleware for Next.js

The code below produces the same results as a wrapper solution.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import nc from "next-connect";

// Handle Error Here
const handler = nc({
  onError: (err, req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.status(500).end(err.toString());
  },
  onNoMatch: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  },
});

handler
  .get(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    // Do some GET stuff
    res.status(200).json(...);
  })
  .post(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    // Do some POST stuff
    res.status(200).json(...);
  });

export default handler;
```

---

Next.js separate API routes into many files if you want the handler to be reusable do it like this.

`/modules/Utils.ts`

```
export const apiHandler = {
  onError: (err, req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.status(500).end(err.toString());
  },
  onNoMatch: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  },
};
```

`/pages/api/index.ts`

```
import nc from "next-connect";
import { apiHandler } from "../modules/Utils";

const handler = nc(apiHandler); // Use handler exported from Utils

handler
  .get((req, res) => {...})
  .post((req, res) => {...});

export default handler;
```

Comment: Probably you should use a factory pattern to create instances of next-connect. It's mentioned in docs in [Common errors](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect#common-errors)

Comment: @ChromeKK Never came across that section in the documentation. Thanks for sharing.